# How do you Ensure a Line Exists and is Uncommented with Ansible LineinFile?

Tags: .htaccess, ansible

How do you ensure a specific line exists in a file and is uncommented with ansible's `lineinfile'

The line I want uncommented (in `.htaccess`):

```
#php_flag display_errors on
```

I have used the following:

```
  - name: Make sure PHP Errors are turned on
    lineinfile: dest={{ www_path }}/.htaccess line="php_flag display_errors on"
```

Comment: Why can't you use config management on the entire `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually your example works as is:

Contents of the `.htaccess` file:

```
#php_flag display_errors on
```

The ansible play:

```
- name: Make sure PHP Errors are turned on
  lineinfile: 
    dest: "{{ www_path }}/.htaccess"
    line: "php_flag display_errors on"
```

Results of ansible-playbook with this play:

```
$ cat .htaccess
#php_flag display_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
```

If the file starts with the line commented you'll see a second line uncommented. To correct this, use a regexp that will match the existing line and replace it:

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /Users/bwhaley/tmp/file
    regexp: '^#php_flag display_errors'
    line: 'php_flag display_errors'
    backrefs: yes
```

Note though that with `backrefs: yes` if the line you want uncommented is not already present and commented, the play will make no change at all.