# Ansible uncomment line in file

Tags: linux, ansible

I want to uncomment a line in file `sshd_config` by using Ansible and I have the following working configuration:

```
- name: Uncomment line from /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: '^#AuthorizedKeysFile'
      line: 'AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

However this config only works if the line starts by `#AuthorizedKeysFile`, but it won't work if the line starts by `# AuthorizedKeysFile` or `#  AuthorizedKeysFile` (spaces between `#` and the words).

How can I configure the regexp so it won't take into account any number of spaces after '#'?

---

I've tried to add another lineinfile option with a space after '#', but this is not a good solution:

```
- name: Uncomment line from /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: '# AuthorizedKeysFile'
      line: 'AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you need zero or more white spaces after the '#' character, the following should suffice:

```
- name: Uncomment line from /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: '^#\s*AuthorizedKeysFile.*$'
      line: 'AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

The modification to your original code is the addition of the `\s*` and the `.*$` in the regex.

Explanation:

`\s` - matches whitespace (spaces, tabs, line breaks and form feeds)

`*` - specifies that the expression to it's left (`\s`) can have zero or more instances in a match

`.*` - matches zero or more of any character

`$` - matches the end of the line

Comment: +: It will work over the desired line and not in possible comments. -: It won't finish with ok state.

Comment: It shouldn't finish in ok state as it has changed the file. First run it will be changed. Second run it will be skipped as it hasn't matched the regex.

Comment: I'm not sure why that matters?

Comment: This is an anti-example for how to do things in Ansible or generally in any language. A change in values requires manual checking and rewriting the code logic.

Comment: I found that you need to add "backrefs=yes" or else on subsequent plays it will add the line to the end of file. I'm using ansible 2.2.1.0. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184126/how-do-you-ensure-a-line-exists-and-is-uncommented-with-ansible-lineinfile

Comment: I think this will fail with `AuthorizedKeysFile /not/the/desired/path # some comment` ... let's be constructive, I have summarised some advice in a new answer

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, you are using the wrong language. With Ansible, you don't tell it what to do, but define the desired state. So it shouldn't be `Uncomment line form /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but `Ensure AuthorizedKeysFile is set to .ssh/authorized_keys`.

Secondly, it doesn't matter what the initial state is (if the line is commented, or not). You must specify a single, unique string that identifies the line.

With `sshd_config` this is possible as the `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive occurs only once in the file. With other configuration files this might be more difficult.

```
- name: Ensure AuthorizedKeysFile is set to .ssh/authorized_keys
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: AuthorizedKeysFile
    line: 'AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

It will match any line containing `AuthorizedKeysFile` string (no matter if it's commented or not, or how many spaces are there) and ensure the full line is:

`AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys`

If the line were different, Ansible will report "changed" state.

On the second run, Ansible will find the `AuthorizedKeysFile` again and discover the line is already in the desired state, so it will end the task with "ok" state.

---

One caveat with the above task is that if any of the lines contains a comment such as a real, intentional comment (for example an explanation in English containing the string `AuthorizedKeysFile`), Ansible will replace that line with the value specified in `line`.

Comment: +: On the second run, Ansible will find the AuthorizedKeysFile again and discover the line is already in the desired state, so it will end the task with "ok" state. -: One caveat with the above task: if any of the lines contains a comment,  Ansible might replace that line with the value specified in line.

Comment: You shouldn't use Ansible to modify existing files unless you know what you are doing. Use templates instead.

Comment: Templates are best for full files. When modifying parts of a file, lineinfile is perfectly acceptable, in fact that is what it's purpose is.

Comment: Sorry, but if you use anything other than template for something as crucial for the security as `sshd_config`, you are asking for trouble. And altogether it's also an incorrect thinking. It doesn't matter if the file is "full" or not, but how many separate processes (roles/plays/external scripts) need to modify distinct sections of a single config file.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about regex.

Comment: @WillemvanKetwich And if you think your "regex" answer is somehow safe from replacing legitimate comments, it is not.

Comment: `# AuthorizedKeysFile - used to show an example where the regex replaces a legitimate comment (this one)`

Comment: @techraf I totally understand your point. But for a scenario like when /etc/ssh/sshd_config is coming from a package. It can still have an updated version of config while If we are using templates we will still use the old one until we update that too to check for the version update :)

Comment: how about matching the whole line?
#AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys -> AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 8):

I should caveat this with @techraf's point that 99% of the time a full **template** of a configuration file is almost always better.

Times I have done `lineinfile` include weird and wonderful configuration files that are managed by some other process, or laziness for config I don't fully understand yet and may vary by distro/version and I don't want to maintain all the variants... yet.

Go forth and learn more Ansible... it is great because you can keep iterating on it from raw bash shell commands right up to best practice.

### lineinfile module

Still good to see how best to configuration manage one or two settings just a little better with this:

```
tasks:
- name: Apply sshd_config settings
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    # might be commented out, whitespace between key and value
    regexp: '^#?\s*{{ item.key }}\s'
    line: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
    validate: '/usr/sbin/sshd -T -f %s'
  with_items:
  - key: MaxSessions
    value: 30
  - key: AuthorizedKeysFile    
    value: .ssh/authorized_keys
  notify: restart sshd

handlers:
- name: restart sshd
  service: 
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```

- `validate` don't make the change if the change is invalid
- `notify`/`handlers` the correct way to restart once only at the end
- `with_items` (soon to become `loop`) if you have  multiple settings
- `^#?` the setting *might* be commented out - see the other answer
- `\s*{{ item.key }}\s` will not match other settings (i.e. `SettingA` cannot match `NotSettingA` or `SettingAThisIsNot`)

Still might clobber a comment like `# AuthorizedKeysFile - is a setting` which we have to live with because there could be a setting like `AuthorizedKeysFile /some/path # is a setting`... re-read the caveat.

### template module

```
- name: Configure sshd
  template:
    src: sshd_config.j2
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "0644"
    validate: '/usr/sbin/sshd -T -f %s'
  notify: restart sshd
handlers:
- name: restart sshd
  service: 
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```

### multiple distro support

And if you are not being lazy about supporting all your distros see this tip

```
- name: configure ssh
  template: src={{ item }} dest={{ SSH_CONFIG }} backup=yes
  with_first_found:
    - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.sshd_config.j2"
    - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.sshd_config.j2"
```

https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modifying-files/modifying-files/

(needs to be updated to a `loop` using the `first_found` lookup)

Comment: this answer deserves way more upvotes, this lineinfile example is a very nice and clean way to maintain a number of key/value style settings in a config file that might change and where you would want the upstream changes without maintaining your own template, thanks @KCD !

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to achieve the same goal with `replace` module.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html

```
- name: Uncomment line from /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  replace:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: '^\s*#+AuthorizedKeysFile.*$'
    replace: 'AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply uncomment a line without setting the value, you can use [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-replace) with backreferences, eg (with a handy loop):

```yaml
- name: Enable sshd AuthorizedKeysFile
  replace:
    path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    # Remove comment and first space from matching lines
    regexp: '^#\s?(\s*){{ item }}(.+)$'
    replace: '\1{{ item }}\2'
  loop:
    - 'AuthorizedKeysFile'
```

This will only remove the first space after the `#`, and so retain any original indenting. It will also retain anything after the key (eg the default setting, and any following comments)

Thanks to the other helpful answers that provided a solid starting point.